# wrap exe to another exe with silent installation command

Tags: windows, packaging

I need help to check what is the tool able achieve this by wrap the exe and lic file and run the command

I have a installer.exe and installer.lic file, the exe support silent install command install the program silently

eg : installer.exe -l installer.lic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm found the solution by using 7zip sfx

https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm

Answer (score 0):

The installer would need to be such that is supports calling commands such as silent install. If it does, you could use a batch file or powershell script. If you need an installer, visual studio provides this ability. There are also third party, install file makers out there.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I don't know how to use visual studio, can the community version able to support this?

Comment: The last time I used the express version it did not support packaging. Newer versions may have changed this, I would check technet. The trial version will give you ninety days to use the full software however if this is a one off. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/windows/topic/321754